Design: How to store boolean values for entites whose name may change?
Let's say I want to design a DB for an FMCG Manufacturer - and they have several business units, and several factories.
BUs: Beauty, Homecare, etc.
Factories: SiteA, SiteB, etc.

Now, I want a table that notes which factories produce (and are associated with) which BU. What would be the best way to do that?
My initial thought was to just make the BUs columns and then associate each row with a factory, and thus store the result as a boolean:
Site    Beauty    Homecare
SiteA   True      False
SiteB   True      True
...

But let's say the business changes the name of "beauty" to "wellbeing" tomorrow. I'd have to edit a table field name, which wouldn't be optimal. So, I thought I'd make another table to associate BU IDs with the names:
BUID  Name
1     Beauty
2     Homecare
...

Now, my previous table showing association can simply become:
Site    BUID    Produced
SiteA   1       True
SiteA   2       False
SiteB   1       True
SiteB   2       True
SiteC   1       False
SiteC   2       False
...

Alternatively, I can simply eliminate the records when false - with a presence of a record representing "true", thus giving me:
Site    BUID    
SiteA   1       
SiteB   1       
SiteB   2       
...

Which of the two options above is the better choice, and why? Or is there a better option?
Or am I just overthinking this?
